# Single Level Search with PrincipalSearcher

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, active-directory, ldap

I just recently started learning C# due to requirements at work, I am trying to write a method that will query a specific OU in Active Directory, and only that OU, no sub-OUs. This is how the method looks:

```
public List<string> getAllActiveUsers()
{
    PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = GetPrincipalContext();
    UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(oPrincipalContext) 
    { 
        Enabled = true 
    };
    PrincipalSearcher oPrincipalSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher(oUserPrincipal);

    List<string> allUsers = new List<string>();

    foreach (var found in oPrincipalSearcher.FindAll())
    {
        allUsers.Add(found.DisplayName.ToString());
    }
    allUsers.Sort();
    return allUsers;
}
```

The method as it is now, will only pull user enabled user accounts, but the problem is that it pulls the accounts in subOUs, which is not desireable. I have Googled for quite some time, with no real answer to the question, I am a novice at best, if there is a suggestion to change the code, please show me what the final method would look like.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Apparently I didn't Google search enough, so I took another whack at it, I came across a suggestion that using GetUnderlyingSearcher() would work, but I still had no idead how to use it. Some additional research yielded what I needed, here's the updated method:

```
public List<string> getAllActiveUsers()
    {
        PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = GetPrincipalContext();
        UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(oPrincipalContext) { Enabled = true };
        PrincipalSearcher oPrincipalSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher(oUserPrincipal);
        //Setting the search scope by going down to DirectorySearcher itself, as it's not possible to set this
        //via PrincipalSearcher directly
        ((DirectorySearcher)oPrincipalSearcher.GetUnderlyingSearcher()).SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;

        List<string> allUsers = new List<string>();

        foreach (var found in oPrincipalSearcher.FindAll())
        {
            allUsers.Add(found.DisplayName.ToString());
        }
        allUsers.Sort();
        return allUsers;
    }
```

Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: So apparently I didn't Google hard enough... The answer was in the GetUnderlyingSearcher() method of PrincipalSearcher.

I went ahead and added this line after the declaration of oPrincipalSearcher:

((DirectorySearcher)oPrincipalSearcher.GetUnderlyingSearcher()).SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;

That fixed it!

Comment: Happens to me all the time... post on SO then find the answer myself.  You should submit this as an answer and accept it.  Otherwise people might overlook the comments section and think there isn't an answer.

Comment: I will as soon as my 8 hours is up, this is literally my first SO post. And my reputation is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bit of code is what resolved my issue:

```
((DirectorySearcher)oPrincipalSearcher.GetUnderlyingSearcher()).SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;
```

With the final method looking like this:

```
public List<string> getAllActiveUsers()
    {
        PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = GetPrincipalContext();
        UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(oPrincipalContext) { Enabled = true };
        PrincipalSearcher oPrincipalSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher(oUserPrincipal);
        //Setting the search scope by going down to DirectorySearcher itself, as it's not possible to set this
        //via PrincipalSearcher directly
        ((DirectorySearcher)oPrincipalSearcher.GetUnderlyingSearcher()).SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;

        List<string> allUsers = new List<string>();

        foreach (var found in oPrincipalSearcher.FindAll())
        {
            allUsers.Add(found.DisplayName.ToString());
        }
        allUsers.Sort();
        return allUsers;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm I'm not familiar with `PrincipalSearcher`, but you might try using `DirectorySearcher` instead.  It has an option `SearchScope` that allows you to set either `OneLevel` or `SubTree` (or `Base`).  Here's some sample code you can try (this is mangled from my production code, so it is untested and may not even compile, but it should give you the idea):

```
DirectorySearcher dsr = new DirectorySearcher();
dsr.SearchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(settings.Path, settings.Username, settings.Password, settings.AuthType);
dsr.PageSize = 100;
dsr.SizeLimit = 0;
dsr.SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;
dsr.Filter = "(&(objectclass=user)(sn=UserLastName))";
dsr.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(new string[] { "sn", "givenName" });
using (SearchResultCollection src = dsr.FindAll())
{
    foreach (SearchResult sr in src)
    {
        string propName = lp.Name;
        ResultPropertyValueCollection rpvc = sr.Properties[propName];
        string val = (string)rpvc[0];
    }
}
```